# Centered sticky menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a piece of code using script with CSS that allows me to have a menu which sticks to the top of the screen when you scroll down.

At the moment it's aligned left and I want it centered under my title and to stay centered when you scroll down.

I've tried changing a few values and using padding but its creating problems and I figured there must be a easier to do it that I'm probably missing.

### HTML

```
    <pre>
    <script>
    $(function() {


    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;


    var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top


        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
     } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }  
    };

    sticky_navigation();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

    });  
   </script>

    <div id="demo_top_wrapper">

    <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
        <div id="sticky_navigation">
            <div class="demo_container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

   </pre>
```

### CSS

```
.demo_container { width:980px; margin:0 auto;padding-left:0 auto; }
#demo_top_wrapper { margin:0 0 20px 0; }
#demo_top { height:100px; padding:20px 0 0 0; }
#my_logo { font:70px Georgia, serif; }


#sticky_navigation_wrapper { width:100%; height:50px; }
#sticky_navigation { width:100%; height:50px; background:url(trans-black-60.png);     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;float:centre }
#sticky_navigation ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:5px; }
#sticky_navigation ul li { margin:0; padding:0; display:inline; }
#sticky_navigation ul li a { display:block; float:left; margin:0 0 0 5px; padding:0 20px; height:40px; line-height:40px; font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, serif; font-weight:bold; color:#ddd; background:#333; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your #sticky_navigation div's width is set at 100%, so it's as big as your page. You have to set the width of the div to "auto" or a precise value (like 400px) or remove it, the set its margin to "auto"
Then, remove "left:0px" from the js code, it sets your div 0px far from the left bound of your page.

css:

```
#sticky_navigation { width:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; height:50px; background:url(trans-black-60.png);     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;float:centre }
.demo_container { margin:auto; text-align:center; }
```

js:

```
 $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0 });
```

Comment: Thank you, that centres the div tag but what about centre the menu inside the div tag because at the minute it is still left and if I try to use padding, it also pads the dive tag to the right when it scrolls?

Comment: No, no, you can center what is contained into the div just using text-align:center; as a css rule for #sticky_navigation

Comment: Yea thats what I thought but it didnt work? its still alligned left?

Comment: add #demo_container { margin:auto; text-align:center; } to your css, I've edited my answer with the code

Comment: Have done what you suggested and added the div tag to the html, no change? It just doesnt want to centre.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote wrong code, just substitute the # tag in "." before "demo_container" as I edited in the answer (the first of your css lines: remove its content and substitute with mine)